# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) - CANNOT POST DATA FORM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am using ajax jquery to POST the data. But, when i click button to POST data, the input name cannot POST, and the answer is NULL in database. THANKS FOR ANSWER

This is my JQUERY

```
$('#btn-save').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: "<?= site_url('transaksi/tambah_kehadiran'); ?>",
          method: "POST",
          data: $('#form-presensi').serialize(),
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(response) {
            if(response.status) {
                setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('transaksi/kehadiran'); ?>"; }, 2000);
                reset();
                alertify.success("Data berhasil ditambah");
                return false;
            } else {
                reset();
                alertify.error("Data gagal ditambah");
                return false;
            }
          }
        });
});
```

This is my Controller

```
public function tambah_kehadiran(){
        $data_kehadiran = array(
            'kode_kehadiran' => $this->input->post("kode_karyawan"),
            'kode_karyawan' => $this->input->post("kode_karyawan"),
            'hari' => $this->input->post("hari"),
            'tanggal' => $this->input->post("tanggal"),
            'jam_masuk' => $this->input->post("jam_masuk"),
            'kode_shift' => $this->input->post("kode_shift"),
            'nama' => $this->input->post("nama"),
            'keterangan' => $this->input->post("keterangan")
        );

        $q = $this->model_transaksi->insert('kehadiran', $data_kehadiran);
        if($q){
            echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array('status' => false));
        }
    }
```

THE RESULT IS

```
Error Number: 1048

Column 'kode_kehadiran' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `kehadiran` (`kode_kehadiran`, `kode_karyawan`, `hari`, `tanggal`, `jam_masuk`, `kode_shift`, `nama`, `keterangan`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/Klinik/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Comment: The setTimeout() line - I think that's causing the error. I think you can just remove that.

Comment: `'kode_kehadiran' => $this->input->post("kode_karyawan"),` - `kode_kehadiran` instead?

Comment: @Mr.Blue in other my code,the code same with above but there is no problem. The problem in my case now, they cannot POST data any one to my Controller

Comment: The `setTimeout()` line is `GET` method, that's why `POST` fails.

Comment: @Mr.Blue that's just for reload my view Mr, and there is no problem in my other code.

Comment: can you show your form?

Comment: "Column 'kode_kehadiran' cannot be null" and all your data is null when it cannot be. This is your problem. Make sure your form `$('#form-presensi').serialize()` is getting the data properly with a console.log. Show view as it's applicable.

Comment: @Alex how i know the console.log from '$('#form-presensi').serialize()' ? can you give me example?

Comment: Just do it in the click function and before ajax the console.log(...)

Comment: @Alex i haved check with console log, and the result that show data from `$('#form-presensi').serialize()` , and when data send to my controller, the result is NULL, there are no data post

Comment: Post relevant parts your view as an edit to the question.

Comment: F12 -> Network -> Check preserve log -> Choose the request -> select header tab and check the value posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rizqon Nurrofik, I have slightly modified your codes for finding the errors producing place. The error seems like there are no errors returning from ajax. I guess your form field name might be array value. I'm not sure, place my code and check it if you get `required field(s) is|are empty` alert value, it means a problem in your view file. not in php file.

**jQuery**

```
$('#btn-save').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?= site_url('transaksi/tambah_kehadiran'); ?>",
        method: "POST",
        data: $('#form-presensi').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.status){      
                alertify.success(response.message);
                reset();
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    window.location.href = "<?= site_url('transaksi/kehadiran'); ?>"; 
                }, 2000);                    
                return false;
            }else{                    
                alertify.error(response.message);
                reset();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function tambah_kehadiran(){
    if($this->input->post() && count(array_filter($this->input->post())) == 8){ // 8 = for 8 fields in your column and if anything empty it will goes to error
        extract($this->input->post());
        $q = $this->model_transaksi->insert('kehadiran', compact('kode_kehadiran','kode_karyawan','hari','tanggal','jam_masuk','kode_shift','nama','keterangan'));
        if($q){
            // success
            echo json_encode(array('status' => true, 'message' => 'Data berhasil ditambah'));
        }else{
            // error
            echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'message' => 'Data gagal ditambah'));
        }
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'message' => 'required field(s) is|are empty'));
    }
}
```